# R - combine a 3D matrix and single vector then select certain month data

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, matrix, dataframe, combinations

i am now having a single date vector `A`  (362 rows) and i have a 3D matrix `B` (dimensions `360*180*3620`)

```
> str(ssta_date)
 POSIXlt[1:362], format: "1981-11-15" "1981-12-15" "1982-01-15" "1982-02-15" "1982-03-15" ...

> dim(ssta_sst)
[1] 360 180 362
```

is it possible to combine `A` and `B` as a data frame or something else. it must match each date and each temperature in the `B` [,,362]. so each date will corresponding to a 360*180 matrix.

Because i am planning to do this t to select certain month data, is there any shortcut to do month data selection without combine the two data sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want, 
you can use `melt` to convert your array to a data.frame, 
and then use `merge` to join it with the other piece of data.
If you want an array at the end, you can use `acast` 
to convert the data.frame back to an array.

```
# Sample data
n <- 10
d <- array( 
  rnorm(n^3),
  dim = c(n,n,n), 
  dimnames = list(
    One   = LETTERS[1:n], 
    Two   = LETTERS[1:n], 
    Three = LETTERS[1:n]
  ) 
)
x <- data.frame( One=LETTERS[1:n], x=runif(n) )

library(reshape2)
d <- melt(d)
d <- merge( d, x, by="One", all=TRUE )
d$result <- d$value + d$x # Do something with the data
acast( d, One ~ Two ~ Three, value.var="result" )
```

Comment: sorry, the method is good, but due to the huge data size, all the time i tried to run it, the program will crash. is there any way to avoid it?